# isotope shuffle after remove and relayout

Tags: jquery-isotope, shuffle

I have a shuffle button that works fine on my Isotope setup until I remove some items. Try deleting a bloc and then a shuffle: http://apany.com/assistants/

```
      $('#shuffle').click(function(){
    $container.isotope('shuffle');
  });

  $('.delete').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $container.isotope('reLayout');
    return false;
  });
```

I am totally out of my depth here. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are using  the jQuery remove function rather than the Isotope remove function. I believe you need to change the remove line to:

```
$container.isotope( 'remove', $(this).parent() );
```